# Are there practical limits to Eloquent ORM when eager loading?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In the section on Eager Loading, https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading, the Laravel guide explains that it is executing a `WHERE... IN...` query.

Is there a practical limit to the number of arguments for the `IN` clause?  For example, if I have 100 values in the clause, should I start looking at different options such as table joins?

Presumably in most cases performance would become the limiting factor before I hit the hard limits of my RDBMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that performance will be an issue unless you have 10K+ rows. You almost always query the table's primary key (`id`), which should have an index and thereby provide fast access.

Hard limits on the number of parameters, however, can be a problem. SQL Server only allows 2100 parameters, SQLite only 999. These limits can be bypassed with [this package](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-param-limit-fix) (self-promotion).

In cases where a `WHERE IN` query is getting too slow, a JOIN won't be faster either.
If you try to fetch 10K+ rows, creating the model objects will also take a significant amount of time.